# android app login to website that uses facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, android-facebook

I have a website which uses facebook login to login to itself. I need to login to my website in an android app. The process of login is usual :

```
1. request to /auth/login
2. redirect to facebook 
3. response from facebook 
4. redirect to /auth/login
5. response from /auth/login has a set-cookie header which basically is all the authentication
```

How do I login to the website in the app?
[example](https://hisaab.herokuapp.com/auth/user). Use the developers tools' network panel to observe the process.